# How do I change Netbeans's webserver port from 8383?

Tags: netbeans

How do I change Netbeans's webserver port from 8383?

I know I could install and use a separate webserver, but I'd prefer to just use the embedded one.
Some of what I've read online makes me think it might not be possible to change the port.  But, then bug https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=222570 makes it sound like using other than 8383 is possible.
I can't find such a setting with the UI.  I searched under the installation directory for 8383 and can't find anything.
So, how do I do this?  I'm using Netbeans 8.0.1.
Thanks.

ADDITIONAL INFO:
I'm using the internal webserver that comes with Netbeans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, definitely not via UI. Looking at [the java class](http://hg.netbeans.org/main-golden/file/25aaf36f9b4d/web.common/src/org/netbeans/modules/web/common/api/WebServer.java), port number seems to be hardcoded in the source. You would have to build the particular NetBeans module and then replace the one in NetBeans installation folder with yours module.

From what I can tell from the issue, it fixes cases when default port 8383 is occupied, IDE uses different one (increment by 1) and thanks to the fixed bug, this incremented port is also used in browser (prior the fix, even with incremented port, old 8383 was being used in browser).

You can file enhancement with request for it.

Answer (score 0):

Under Window / Services / Servers you'll find every registered server. Right-click on your server, choose "Properties" and under the "Connection"-tab you can define your port.

(You haven't mentioned which server you are using, but that's the way where you usually define your port).

Comment: I just added that I'm using the internal webserver.  Under Window / Services I have Databases, Web Services, Hudson Builders, Task Repositories, and JS Test Driver but no Servers option.

Comment: Does this link help: https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/php_5_4_support_built ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find Servers option either and I'm using NetBeans v8.0.2. But you can use an external server [ex. IIS, Apache] as an workaround: right-click the project in Project Window > Properties > Run. Then change the Web Server to External and Project URL to your desired address.
If your project is not in an web accessible directory you must make it web accessible first by configuring your web server or adding it in an web accessible location.